# crontab execute a script every minute

Tags: php, linux, cron

my script is below,and

```
lynx -mime_header "http://xxxxx.com/testdownload.php";
```

I am running this every 1 minute like below.

```
* *    * * *   root    /data/script/myxcript.sh  &> /data/tmp/myscript.log
```

But its not running,can anyone guide me,how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to execute this job as root or use the root's crontab. In anycase, you can not do that by simply adding the word root to the cron job.

Try removing the word `root` and placing the job in root's crontab.

Comment: Thanks for reply,i am the root

Comment: In that case you should be able to just remove the word `root` from that line and it should work.

Comment: do i need to restart the cron

Comment: Whenever you edit the crontab file, it should be reloaded automatically. When I leave my editor after `crontab -e` it gives me this message: `"crontab: installing new crontab"`. I do not believe that you need to restart the actual cron service...

Comment: I am editing my crobtab: pico /etc/crontab and then when I finish editing I press ctrl+X

Comment: @arok - yes... that should be enough. You **should** however, be editing your crontab with `crontab -e`. It'll use your default editor which you might want to change to what you're used to - pico.

Comment: I think that is the problem... You're editing the file with an external editor so the system doesn't know to reload it. This is similar to working with the sudoers file - you never actually edit the file but rather go though the `visudo` command.